# Matching exact elements in a set where order doesn't matter

Tags: python, set

I'm new to python and I'm trying to match the exact elements between two sets, regardless of order. So if my 2 sets are:

```
reflist = [1],[2,3,4],[5,6]
qlist = [1,2,3,4],[6,5]
```

The number of matches should be 1, which is 5,6

I tried to write the following loop to match the elements in qlist against reflist, and count the number of matches:

```
i = 0
count = 0
for each in qlist:
    while i < len(qlist):
        if each.split(",").sort == reflist[i].split(",").sort:
            count = count + 1
        i = i + 1
print count
```

However, I keep getting count = 0, even if the order of 5 and 6 in qlist is 5,6. Would really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Convert everything to a set of `frozensets` and find the intersection. Since order does not matter, this should be fine.

Comment: For example, `set(map(frozenset, reflist)).intersection(map(frozenset, qlist))` and if all you want is the number of matches, just enclose everything with `len`. The drawback with this is that it does not account for duplicates (if you have any).

Comment: the initial data `reflist = [1],[2,3,4],[5,6] ...` is invalid, make corrections

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It becomes a tuple of lists.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, it's obvious that it becomes as some of that, but it should be specified evidently without confusion. Posting that is a bad habit

Comment: @OP, can there be duplicates in your "sets"?

Comment: Thanks for the help. No, there aren't any duplicates in the sets.

Comment: @darrrn How is your code not even erroring out? Both `each` and `reflist[i]` are lists, and you are applying a string method of `split(",")` on them. Can it be that your code is not running at all, and therefore you are getting the initial value of `count = 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no duplicates in your "sets",  convert your "sets" to a set of `frozenset`s, and find the *set intersection* -

```
i = set(map(frozenset, reflist))
j = map(frozenset, qlist)

len(i.intersection(j))
1
```

Answer (score 1):

This could do:

If you have no duplicates:

```
matches = [x for x in map(set, reflist) if x in map(set, qlist)]
```

If you have duplicates:

```
matches = [x for x in map(sorted, reflist) if x in map(sorted, qlist)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `collections.Counter()` for this:

```
from collections import Counter

reflist = [[1],[2,3,4],[5,6]]
qlist = [[1,2,3,4],[6,5]]

result = [list(x.keys()) for x in [Counter(y) for y in reflist] if x in [Counter(y) for y in qlist]]

print(result)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[[5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my one-liner, using `frozenset`s and `and`:

```
len(set(map(frozenset, qlist)) and set(map(frozenset, reflist)))
```

I understand you are new to Python, hence I will answer your question using your own method, just for the sake of recording the basic straightforward answer for future reference.

First of all, your code shouldn't run at all. It must error out, because both `each` and `reflist[i]` are lists, and you are applying a string method of `split(",")` on them. Therefore you are getting the initial value of `count = 0`. You must check in the first place whether your code is even touching all the elements of `qlist` and `reflist`. This is not [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), hence I will leave it to you to run this and see the answer:

```
i = 0
count = 0
for each in qlist:
    while i < len(qlist):
        print i
        print each
        print reflist[i]
        i = i + 1
```

Keep in mind: **You don't have to iterate on index! You can just loop over the elements of iterables directly!** This is the answer you are looking for:

```
match = [] # Optional, to see all the matching elements
count = 0 
for q in qlist:
    for r in reflist:
        if set(q) == set(r):
            print q, r
            match.append(q)
            count += 1 
print match
print count, len(match)
```